# How can I listen to a YouTube video on my Ipad?

Tags: ipad, youtube

How can I view a YouTube video on my iPad?

My iPad plays any other video (like on FaceBook) but YouTube doesn't work.

Do I need to subscribe to YouTube in order to view videos?

Comment: If you can explain what you mean with "doesn't work" I might be able to update the answer to be a more exact solution for your issue.

Plus, what iPad are you using? And what version of iOS are you running?

Comment: Also - you might list a specific URL (choosing something tasteful and appropriate for all ages and regions) since the vast majority of URL simply play from within mobile safari without needing any sort of app or tweaks...

Answer (score 1):

Did you download the **YouTube App?** This is the easiest way, and no - you **don't need** an account to watch YouTube via an iPad.

Comment: ah maybe thats it. I might need to download the app. thanks I will try that!